# Selector is exceeding selector-max-specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity, stylelint

Here's the CSS that I have:

```css
.tab {
  border: 0;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-height: 48px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}
.tab:not([data-selected]) {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.tab[data-selected] {
  background-color: $white;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  z-index: 2;
}
.tab[data-selected]:first-of-type {
  margin-right: -8px;
}
.tab[data-selected]:last-of-type {
  margin-left: -8px;
}
.tab[data-selected]:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
.tab:first-of-type {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
}
.tab:last-of-type {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-top-right-radius: 12px;
}
```

Having problem with this bit here:

```css
.tab[data-selected]:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

I'm trying to select the **middle child** when it is selected. My stylelint is complaining like so:

```
Expected "`.tab[data-selected]:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)`" to have a specificity no more than "0,3,2"
```

How do I approach this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The total specificity of your selector

```css
.tab[data-selected]:not(:first-of-type):not(:last-of-type)
```

is (0,4,0), which is 1 over the limit of (0,3,2).

You can increase `selector-max-specificity` to accommodate this selector since the difference is so small.

Or if you'd rather not do that, you can refactor your `&[data-selected]` CSS rules like this. Apply both negative margins by default, then selectively remove the negative margins from `&:first-of-type` and `&:last-of-type`, thereby eliminating the need for the double negation:

```css
    &[data-selected] {
        background-color: $white;
        margin-left: -8px;
        margin-right: -8px;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        z-index: 2;

        &:first-of-type {
            margin-left: 0; /* Preserve negative margin-right */
        }

        &:last-of-type {
            margin-right: 0; /* Preserve negative margin-left */
        }
    }
```

Note that the margin directions are swapped in the two nested rules since we're trying to preserve the now-existing negative margins instead of adding them where they weren't there before.

Comment: A hypothetical alternative exists in the form of `.tab[data-selected]:not(:first-of-type, :last-of-type)` with a specificity (0,3,0), except it's still not supported anywhere other than Safari and Firefox... the latter of which only started supporting it *a month ago*, *over five years* after the former. Ugh.